# So that earthquake, did you check your math?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a short story in one of my dad's books about a seismologist living in California who was predicting 'the big one' on the San Andreas fault, but kept arguing with the computer about the math. I can't remember the author, title or any other identifier, but the last line was something like:

> "Well, I'll be. The computer was right!"

There may have been mild profanity.

> Everyone else leaves California, but instead of California falling into the Pacific, the rest of the country falls into the Atlantic. He is the sole survivor.

Comment: Roughly when did you read the story? Was it in an anthology? Magazine? Website? What language was it in?

Comment: I believe that it was over ten years ago when my dad sold his library, including the book with this story. There were other short stories in the book, but I do not remember them at all.

Comment: The computer's estimate of the seismic vector was 180 degrees off from his. That story is in *Cosmic Laughter*, an anthology of humorous science fiction short stories edited by Joe Haldeman, which I read circa 1985  (I remember the cover photo of a metallic-painted hand drawing a smiley-face in the substance of the starry sky with its finger). I don't remember the title or author of the story, but I'll see if I can dig it up...

Comment: Sounds like a comedy.

Comment: @fredsbend, not exactly, but Fun nonetheless.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Ben Bova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Bova)'s short story ["A Slight Miscalculation"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52522), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, August 1971](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61004), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v041n02_1971-08_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v041n02_1971-08_PDF#page/n1/mode/2up).

> Beyond the parking lot, where the eucalyptus trees used to be, was the edge of a cliff, where still-steaming rocks and raw earth tumbled down to a foaming sea.
>
> Nathan staggered to the cliff's edge and looked out across the water, eastward. Somehow he knew that the nearest land was Europe.
>
> "Son of a bitch," he said with unaccustomed vehemence. "The computer was right after all."

Comment: @user14111 - I wish there was a wiki article on the quotes you've provided in your bio.  They all sound like bits of interesting fiction I should be reading...

Answer (score 4):

From memory, it sounds like Arthur C. Clarke and Mike McQuay's "[Richter 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_10)" where Lewis Crane tries to predict and prevent earthquakes (by spot welding the plates). However, their computer system is compromised to make a earthquake prediction months earlier than it actually happens.

Comment: No, It was definitely a short story. Otoh, care to guess what gust got added to my reading list?

Answer (score 1):

"A Slight Miscalculation" by Ben Bova. is the story you have descrbed, and one I have been looking for many decades! I couldn't remember the title nor the sci fi short story collection where I found and read the story. I read it in college in 1984. No "old" comments, please. ;>)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Please consider taking [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately your answer doesn't add anything to [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83722/13418) existing and already accepted answer. Please answer questions only if you add some valuable information.